# How to update data continuously in UI text box control using windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-8

Im developing a small Tcp Client Socket application in windows phone. Actually i have a text box, in that whatever the data received from a TCP server, should update continuously in UI text box control.

```
      while (val)
        {

            result = Receive();
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                txtOutput.Text += result;
            }));

        }
```

Here in above code, method receive() will receive string data and should update in textbox control but it is not happening,no data is updating to it.
Can any one suggest, how can i resolve this.

Comment: Did you try binding the data to the `TextBox`? Are you using the MVVM model?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the line txtOutput.Text += result to see if it is actually hit?

Comment: Binding doesn't seem to solve the question, because Shashank wants to append the new string into the textbox.
Dispatcher might not be even called at all.
What I suggest is to put a breakpoint right after the Receive() method being called to check what is being put in the result variable, and then a breakpoint in the `txtOutput.Text += result;` to see if this is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Just telling you what i have been advised, *"avoid Dispatcher, CoreDispatcher, etc. There are always better solutions."*

Below is the piece of code worked for me for both wp8 and wp8.1 WinRT app,

```
IProgress<object> progress = new Progress<object>(_ => UpdateTicker());
Task.Run(async () =>
{
  while (val)
  {
    progress.Report(null);
  }
});
```

where `UpdateTicker()` method contains your instructions, in this case...

```
public void UpdateTicker()
{
    result = Receive();
    txtOutput.Text += result;
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone, who given a valuable response for my post.

Hi Nishchith,
I tried your code, but it dint works for me

Here is my logic used to update textbox continuously with data received from TCP server.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
    using PhoneApp3.Resources;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Text;
    using Windows.Phone.Networking;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace PhoneApp3
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    Socket _socket = null;
    static ManualResetEvent _clientDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    const int TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = 1000;
    const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
    const int ECHO_PORT = 9055;  // The Echo protocol uses port 7 in this sample
    const int QOTD_PORT = 49152; // The Quote of the Day (QOTD) protocol uses port 17 in this sample
    string result = string.Empty;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnEcho_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
           SocketClient client = new SocketClient();
            Connect(txtRemoteHost.Text, ECHO_PORT);
             //close();

    }

    public void Connect(string hostName, int portNumber)
    {
        DnsEndPoint hostEntry = new DnsEndPoint(hostName, portNumber);
        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = hostEntry;
        socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            result = e.SocketError.ToString();
            _clientDone.Set();
        });
        _clientDone.Reset();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        _socket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        _clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        bool val;
        if (result == "Success")
        {
            val = true;
        }
        else
        {
            val = false;
        }


        IProgress<object> progress = new Progress<object>(_ => UpdateTicker());
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
             while (val)
              {
                progress.Report(null);
              }
        });

    }


  public void UpdateTicker()
    {
       result = Receive();
       string[] strsplit = result.Split(' ');
       txtOutput.Text = strsplit[1];
    }

    public string Receive()
    {
        string response = "Operation Timeout";
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = _socket.RemoteEndPoint;
            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE], 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
                {
                    // Retrieve the data from the buffer
                    response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
                    response = response.Trim('\0');

                }
                else
                {
                    response = e.SocketError.ToString();
                }

                _clientDone.Set();
            });

            _clientDone.Reset();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
           _socket.ReceiveAsync(socketEventArg);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            _clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        }
        else
        {
            response = "Socket is not initialized";
        }

        return response;
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            _socket.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}